# google analytics visits are more than page views

Tags: view, google-analytics, tracking

Hi have a webpage that uses many filters but for some odd reason the visits in all of these filters are greater than the # of views. This is the source code used to track in my page.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);  // global tracker
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.somedomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['x._setAccount', 'UA-YYYYYY-1']); // site tracker
_gaq.push(['x._setDomainName', '.somedomain.com']);
_gaq.push(['x._trackPageview']);
(function() {

var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

})();

</script>
```

Here is a screengrab of the stats on Oct 23 2011. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/sourcemediumdetailgoogl.jpg/
From then on, the visits are always larger than the # of page views. Here is the link to the screengrab for one of the filters that is not showing accurate data. This is also in my filter which uses "include" as the filter type.

```
^/site/newfolder/
```

Answer (score 1):

Filters in Google Analytics are confusing and haven't been updated for a while. So sometimes it's not effective specially when used together with events, social interactions, transactions and customvars. in some corner cases and may lead to scenarios like these.

A new visit starts in GA when the first hit is received by GA. Not the first pageview. The hit may be any of the following types:

- Pageview
- Event
- Ecommerce Transaction
- Ecommerce  Item
- Social Interactions
- UserDefined (triggered by the deprecated method _setVar)

If you see a visit that has no pageviews it probably has at least one of the other hits above.

Depending on the type of hit you have leaking into your web property the solution to filter these out might be different. If what you have leaking in are Social interactions, then you have a worse problems. I'm unaware of any methods to filter out social interactions, they all fail.

You can always ignore these visits by applying a segment that includes only visits with Pageviews grater then 0.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which hit type the visits are? Is it Event or social interactions? I doubt it is any of the ecommerce since it's not an ecommerce site. Also setVar is not in the code. Right now on a different profile & date, I got 471 visits and 3 pageviews which is bizarre to me. Out of the 471 visits, 32 are direct traffic but only 2 out of those 32 created a pageview. Where did the other 30 visit come from? Why didnt they generate a pageview?

Comment: Create a segment to see only visits with 0 pageviews and examine the Content>Event report, Audience>Social reports, Demographic>User Defined Reports and the ecommerce reports.